# C# First Simple Class

Tags: c#, class, console

So I started learning C# (actually this is my 3rd day), and I am poking at it left and right.

So I am using `Console`, and I created my first very simple class

```
using System.Timers;

public class Star
{
    private int x, y;

    public Star(int fx, int fy)
    {
        Create(fx, fy);
        Move();
    }

    private void Create(int fx, int fy)
    {
        this.x = fx;
        this.y = fy;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(this.x, this.y);
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    private void Move()
    {
        Timer aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 500;
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Start();

    }
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(this.x, this.y);
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
}
```

}

I have a main Program loop, which executes non-stop waiting for user input and it has different states.

```
while (true)
{
    if (Mode == 0)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(tX, tY);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Write("[ " + System.DateTime.Now + " ]");

        Cursor(Selection, OldSelection);
    }
    if (Mode == 2)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
            Star myStar = new Star(r.Next(nScreenWidth), r.Next(nScreenHeight));
    }


    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (Mode == 0)
        {
            switch (keyInfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    OldSelection = Selection;

                    if (Selection == 4) Selection = 0;
                    else Selection++;
                break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    OldSelection = Selection;

                    if (Selection == 0) Selection = 4;
                    else Selection--;
                break;
                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    if (Selection == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Mode = 1;
                    }

                    if (Selection == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Mode = 2;
                    }

                    if (Selection == 4) return;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            MainMenu();
            Mode = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I start the Stars (mode 2) it displays stars at random positions, but if I exit this, the Objects don't die immediately, their timers are still executing and they are positioning the Cursor-position, and screwing up the Main Menu. I probably this something horrible here, but I have no idea what.

Regards 
Robert

**FINAL WORKING EXAMPLE**

After Chating a bit on IRC , I was told that it would be best to use one Timer , since I already have a main loop . I altered my code like this .

First the Class

```
   public class Star : IDisposable
    {
        public static int instances = 0;

        public Star(int fx, int fy)
        {
            Create(fx, fy);
            Animate();
        }

        int x, y, animpos;

        private void Create(int fx, int fy)
        {
            this.x = fx;
            this.y = fy;
            this.animpos = 0;

            instances++;
        }

        public void Animate()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(this.x, this.y);

            switch (animpos)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        Console.Write("+");
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    {
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    break;
            }
            animpos++;
            if (animpos == 3) { animpos = 0; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            instances--;
        }
    }
```

and the then the Main Loop from the Programm , only the relevant part :

```
        if (Mode == 2)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

            if(Star.instances < 30)
            {
                Star myStar = new Star(r.Next(nScreenWidth-1), r.Next(nScreenHeight-1));
                stars.Add(myStar);
            }

            if (stars.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach(var star in stars)
                {
                    star.Animate();
                }
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, nScreenHeight-1);
            Console.Write("NUMBER OF STARS ON SCREEN : " + Star.instances);
        }
```

I left the Dispose there , just to remember this , in the future I will hopefully produce more complex code . But I guess it is not really needed for this .

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to create 10 instances of your `Star` class every 500 milliseconds, but you are not maintaining references to these objects.

You need to add them to a collection, for example a list...

```
static List<Star> stars = new List<Star>();

for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
    Star myStar = new Star(r.Next(nScreenWidth), r.Next(nScreenHeight));
    stars.Add(myStar);
}
```

Then, when you exit to main menu, you need to dispose of these instances explicitly so you can ensure their timers are no longer firing.

In C#, it is common practice to implement the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in a class you wish to be able to explicitly dispose of...

```
public class Star : IDisposable
{
    ...
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (aTimer != null)
        {
            aTimer.Dispose();
            aTimer = null;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You can then dispose of your Star instances by calling dispose on them...

```
if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    foreach (var star in stars)
        star.Dispose();
    Console.Clear();
    MainMenu();
    Mode = 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it almost works, please see UPDATE above . I think something else is seriously wrong with my Class . I have no idea why but it looks like the this.x and this.y looses it's value or something , not always but sometimes before it gets to the OnTimedEvent.

Comment: I've got my answer from IRC ... it seems like I cannot have a seperate timer for each object ... since the SetCursorPosition on the console might fire for multiple objects at once... and the position is off then . I will refactor the code , and create on main timer which then animates all the stars . Thank you